# Latex error: "Math Processing Error"

Tags: support, math-display

When I access stats exchange at home my browser doesn't process the LaTeX part of the posts. Instead, I just see

"Math Processing Error"

Any ideas?

---

At home I use:

1. ipod touch
2. Ubunto Linux with firefox 3.6.6

Comment: I noticed the same problem on Ubuntu using firefox earlier today as well. I'm not sure whether that browser has javascript enabled, but I thought it probably did.

Comment: Javascript is enabled. When I load a page I get "failed to load: ..../something.js"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. Clear the cache!

However, it still doesn't work with my ipod.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem on my iPhone. I guess the mobile safari browser is not supported.

As for firefox on linux, I think that should work. Do you have javascript enabled?

Comment: I'm almost certain I have javascript enabled. I'll check tonight.

Comment: Curious... I have no problem on my iPhone (v4).